# gdal_grid not creating output file - complaining output name is too long

Tags: python, gdal

I have the following python try statement to create a gridded tif from a shapefile with already pre-set options

```
subprocess.call(f'gdal_grid -a nearest:radius1={cell_size}:radius2={cell_size}:angle=0.0:min_points=0:nodata=0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff -txe {txextent} -tye {tyextent} -tr {resolution} -zfield z {shapefile} {output_file}.tif')
```

Initially `subprocess.call(f'gdal_grid -a nearest:radius1={cell_size}:radius2={cell_size}:angle=0.0:min_points=0:nodata=0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff -txe {txextent} -tye {tyextent} -tr {resolution} -zfield z {shapefile} {output_file}.tif')` was providing me with an error that the filename was too long, so I added in the exceptions to pass that.

However, my output_file wasn't being created so I need to get past the name issue in order to create my output_file

Comment: what is your value of `output_file`? did you try a shorter name?

Comment: Did you try to use a hardcoded value for the output file for eliminating problems with using preset variables, which you can fix later once you get the process to work? I suppose that you have already tested that your gdal_grid command works from command line without Python.

Comment: @user30184 yes it works fine from the command line, just in the python script is the issue. The output_file name is a format like so ```2022_TestData_TrialNo2_Survey_25m_BD_ITM_Zvalue.tif```

Comment: I usually get that error when I'm not passing the correct string to subprocess

Comment: You should avoid leading digits in names used in GIS.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your command (slightly modified) with GDAL 3.6.2 (OSGeo4W) and I did not that error.

```
subprocess.call(f'gdal_grid -a nearest:radius1=1:radius2=1:angle=0.0:min_points=0:nodata=0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff -tr 1 1 -txe 0 1 -tye 0 1 test.shp 2022_TestData_TrialNo2_Survey_25m_BD_ITM_Zvalue.tif')

Warning 1: Option min_points ignored
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```